# Plural to singular

Tags: postgresql

I've seen comments about an inflector extension in Postgres, but I can't find the actual extension to use.

So, instead of creating and maintaining a transformation table between plural and singular words, is there an extension in Postgres that already does this?

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing. The snowball dictionaries for PostgreSQL full text search don't really provide that.

Comment: Which comments?  It would be easier to figure out what they were talking about if we could read them ourselves. There is an English stemmer but that is not quite what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks. Funny thing is the comments came from ChatGPT and it actually showed the code. But none of the websites referenced in the response has that actual code. I'll have a accept that there's no extension available.